# How to upgrade my HDD and keep my ubuntu 11.10 instalation

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace my disk without having to rebuild my Ubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install)

What is the best way to upgrade my 200 gb HDD to a new one of 500 gb but - and this is the tricky part - keep my ubuntu instalation.
I curently have 2 partitions hda1 with the ubuntu 11.10 instalation and another partition hda5 with the home folder.
On the new HDD I want to keep the same format 1 partition with ubuntu and another with the home folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot a live CD with both HDDs attached, start the *Partition Editor* (`gparted`), copy and paste the partitions from one drive to the other:

1. In the top right corner select your old hard disk.
2. Select a partition you want to copy (right-click → "Copy"):

   [image]
3. In the top right corner select your new hard disk.
4. Paste the copied partition into unallocated space (right-click → "Paste"):

   [image]
5. Resize if you want (right-click on the partition → "Resize/Move")

This will keep the unique identifiers of the partitions, so you shouldn't need to adjust anything after cloning the drive.

The final part is to re-install GRUB:

1. Note the root partition name of your new HDD (for **example** /dev/sdb1).
2. Open a gnome-terminal and run (sorry, I don't know a GUI way to do it, but it's just a couple of commands):

   1. `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`
   2. `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sdb`
   3. `sudo umount /mnt`

   Make sure you use the **disk** name at the end of point 2!

That's it, reboot with only your new HDD and you should be fine.

---

Some advise: **Do backups first!** Only run one operation at a time and not all at once (so: copy → (resize) → copy → ...).

Comment: Because I admit I am a newbi a gui solution is the best but what about the grub from the MBR?

Comment: Oops, sorry, forgot about that. But you can do that after the cloning while still running the live CD. Will edit my answer.

Comment: Did it. Worked like a charm. And a lot faster than I imagined.

Comment: Done, and checked. Still works like a charm for 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Live CD and DD one drive to the next then resize the partitions using gparted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a disk imaging and cloning software such as [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).