# Recommended total system backup solution

Tags: 11.10, backup, deja-dup

I already searched a bit around the answers here, but nothing satisfied me.
I want a back-up solution that makes a total back-up, so that I can restore my Ubuntu system in case of major failures, like HDD failing.

As far as I can see, I have 2 choices:

1. Backing up with Deja Dup to an external disk. This is fine and I am already doing it, but in case my HDD fails, and I make a new Ubuntu install on a new disk, will Deja Dup be able to restore all my settings and stuff from the backed up files? If it can, then what other files/folders should I add in Deja Dup to back-up?  Currently I have set only the recommended /home folder. Is there a point in telling Deja Dup to back-up everything under "/" ?
2. Disk/partition cloning software. This would be something similar to Norton ghost. Is there software like this with a nice GUI that you could recommend for Ubuntu? And even better, it would be nice if Ubuntu's liveCD could recognize such a clone at install step.

I am using 11.10.

Comment: I just found out on the develpper's website that he is shutting down remastersys See http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you have lots of free space, and that free space is
highly available. In a Debian system, you really only need to
back up what's in /home and perhaps /etc. Then you can get
a list of all packages installed like so:

```
dpkg --get-selections > installed-software
```

and to restore:

```
dpkg --set-selections < installed-software && dselect
```

Deja-dup, or just using duplicity directly should suit
your needs and save you a ton of space compared to
saving binary copies of your HD. It'll be faster too.

**6/19/2013**
I've written detailed instructions on how to automate duplicity (crontab) and
use passphrase protected gpg encryption.

- [au] [Automating duplicity backups using cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309765/automating-duplicity-backups-using-cron/309766#309766)
- [origin] http://peterpetrakis.blogspot.com/2013/06/automating-and-encrypting-duplicity.html

Comment: So you are saying that it's enough to set Deja-Dup back-up /home and /etc ?

Comment: Correct, because /etc doesn't have a list of every package you've installed. Pretty sure that information lives in /var. You'll need /etc to restore any PPAs you've applied but you still need a record  of *what* you installed from there.

Best thing would be to create an additional cron job that runs the aforementioned command and deposits it in your $HOME, that way dejadup has you covered.

Comment: Great. I'll create then a cron job with "dpkg --get-selections > installed-software" to get the list of installed software, and set up deja-dup with /home + /etc.

Answer (score 5):

I have just restored a system, myself. I am a newbie to Ubuntu, but I have learned a lot and I am a fan of multi-partitions.

Backing up /etc; well I don't know, but having a record of 'fstab' is essential and during the re-installation, remembering to only format the / partition is also important. As a result of having a mount point at `/home/my-name`for my data partition, the most important thing that I discovered as a direct result of the re-install, was the need to immediately revert fstab. This required a reboot following the system installation, (just like "Windows"),as I was unable to invoke gedit from the command line straight away.

The benefit is avoiding the need to restore to `/home/my-name`. It is enough of a chore having to re-install all the previously installed programs.

To be doubly safe a monthly clone of the entire hard drive is good. 'dd' leaves you hanging in space without a clue as to what is going on. 'DDRESCUE' keeps you informed. I shall take a look at 'Clonezilla'. Backups with deja dup however, seem to restore data just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Professionally, we use Clonezilla to do full disk and partition clones. It can image the disk to an external USB, SFTP, or NFS shares. It compresses the image and in some cases is able to do partition resizing based upon disk size.

http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: On my disk I have multiple partitions. sdb4 is my linux and sdb5 my swap. Can Clonezilla clone only those partitions form the disk?

Comment: What about using Deja Dup to back up / and then after a fresh install of ubuntu, make a restore?

Comment: I have made a / back-up in Deja Dup, home it helps. Thanks for the clonezilla tip though

Answer (score 2):

you need remastersys, it backs up everything, all installed apps, the whole lot. back in time or deja dup are good, but to get YOUR system back the way you had it, remastersys is great for backing up your system

get it here http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/

be sure to read the guides and you cant go wrong

Comment: The development of remastersys has been discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a command line tool called **dd**

This will copy everything byte for byte, even the uuid (which you would have to change if you wanted to have them both bootable at the same time).

There are [disk/partition cloning instructions here](http://www.sudo-juice.com/how-to-clone-a-partition-or-hard-drive-in-ubuntu-linux/)

In my experience, doing this every so often keeps a solid backup of your system, and when you want to revert I just format the newer partition and copy my backup back in.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install for Question/Answers here on AskUbuntu of how to clone your drive with dd (and other programs)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a Disk/partition cloning software like Norton Ghost with a nice GUI?
Use [Redo](http://redobackup.org/)!

Is open, very easy, partitioning and other tools included and you can surf the web while you clone, back up or restore your disk/partition