# Automating duplicity backups using cron

Tags: cron, duplicity, ssh-agent

How do I automate duplicity backups using cron using gpg encryption and the ssh backend?

Answer (score 6):

## Background

Original Reference: http://peterpetrakis.blogspot.com/2013/06/automating-and-encrypting-duplicity.html

Having suffered data loss in the past and hacking on storage suggests that
it's a good idea to have regular backups. I wanted redundancy in case my
local server failed and I wanted to encrypt my backups using a password
protected gpg key.

The current solution uses a passphrase kept in plain text outside of the
backup path. I plan to investigate moving the gpg key to a smartcard and
using a pin key to unlock it instead. If anyone has any additional solutions
please describe them in detail.

## Persisting requisite environmental variables

Running anything from cron detaches it from your current environment, you lose
all of the variables describing things like your ssh-agent gpg-agent, stuff you
need to begin to communicate with the remote server.

I took a simple approach, in my ~.bashrc I created the following.

```
cat > ~/.backenvrc << EOF
# used by crontab backup script
export SSH_AGENT_PID=$SSH_AGENT_PID
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK
export GPG_AGENT_INFO=$GPG_AGENT_INFO
export GPGKEY=XXX-insert-your-gpg-key-here-XXX
EOF
```

and simply source this from the backup script referenced in my crontab,
I merely need only login once to populate this file.

## Setting up the Crontab

```
# crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
MAILTO=ppetraki@localhost
BACKUP=/home/ppetraki/Documents/System/Backup
#
0 0  * * *      /usr/bin/crontab -l  > $BACKUP/crontab-backup
0 0  * * *      /usr/bin/dpkg --get-selections > $BACKUP/installed-software
0 0  * * *      /usr/local/bin/ppetraki-backup.sh inc
0 0  * * Fri    /usr/local/bin/ppetraki-backup.sh full
```

Note that I am also backing up my crontab and my list of installed software,
eventually I will move this into another script that also does things like

1) backup my bookmarks from chrome and firefox

2) backup mail in a non-binary format

The current cron format performs an incremental backup every night and a
full backup every Friday.

## Driver script

This wraps the invocation of duplicity and acquires the necessary environmental
variables. Duplicity itself can be hairy with all the command line switches
and even more of a burden if you have multiple targets. I have redundant backups,
first to a local server and to a remote service provided by rsync.net (great customer
support!). I found  [horcrux](http://chrispoole.com/project/horcrux/) to be a wonderful, lightweight, duplicity wrapper to suit my needs.

The driver script, which is external to my backup path, also contains my GPG passphrase
to encrypt my backups. Eventually I wish to move to a smartcard driven system [illustrated here] (http://blog.josefsson.org/2011/10/11/unattended-ssh-with-smartcard/)

[/usr/local/bin/ppetraki-backup.sh]

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
action=$1

export USER=XXX
export HOME=/home/$USER

source $HOME/.backenvrc

echo "verifying environment"
echo "gpg-agent: ${GPG_AGENT_INFO}"
echo "gpg-key:   ${GPGKEY}"
echo "ssh-agent-pid:   ${SSH_AGENT_PID}"
echo "ssh-auth-sock:   ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}"

if [ -z $action ]; then
  echo "requires an action!"
  exit 1
fi

export PASSPHRASE=

[ -z $PASSPHRASE ] && exit 1

echo "begin"

for config in local_backup remote_backup
do
  horcrux clean   $config
  horcrux $action $config
done
```

## Using horcrux to wrangle duplicity

Horcrux has the notion of profiles that takes all the complexity out of managing 
the duplicity CLI. Here's an example of a profile.

```
cat /home/ppetraki/.horcrux/local_backup-config
destination_path="rsync://192.168.1.XXX/backups/personal"
```

```
 cat ~/.horcrux/local_backup-exclude
- /home/ppetraki/Sandbox
- /home/ppetraki/Bugs
- /home/ppetraki/Downloads
- /home/ppetraki/Videos
- /home/ppetraki/.xsession-errors
- /home/ppetraki/.thumbnails
- /home/ppetraki/.local
- /home/ppetraki/.gvfs
- /home/ppetraki/.systemtap
- /home/ppetraki/.adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache
- /home/ppetraki/.thunderbird
- /home/ppetraki/.mozilla
- /home/ppetraki/.config/google-googletalkplugin
- /home/ppetraki/.config/google-chrome
- /home/ppetraki/.cache
- /home/ppetraki/**[cC]ache*
```

I found it problematic to backup only sub directories of things like mozilla
and google-chrome, instead I will write an additional script to cherry pick
those files for backup.

The main horcrux config file

```
cat ~/.horcrux/horcrux.conf 
source="/home/ppetraki/"          # Ensure trailing slash
encrypt_key=XXXXXX     # Public key ID to encrypt backups with
sign_key='-'             # Key ID to sign backups with (leave as '-' for no signing)

use_agent=false          # Use gpg-agent?
remove_n=3               # Number of full filesets to remove
verbosity=5              # Logs all the file changes (see duplicity man page)
vol_size=25              # Split the backup into 25MB volumes
full_if_old=30D         # Cause 'full' operation to perform a full
                         # backup if older than 360 days
backup_basename='backup' # Directory name for local backups (i.e., destination
                         # /Volumes/my_drive/backup/ or /media/my_drive/backup/)
dup_params='--use-agent' # Parameters to pass to Duplicity
```

This is great as it reduces a backup invocation to this:

```
 $ horcrux inc local_backup
```

## Monitoring

I defined MAILTO in my crontab and also installed mutt and the reconfigured
postfix for local mail delivery. Every night I get a progress report on how 
the backups ran.

## Conclusion

I've spent quite a bit of time determining how to automate this in and provide
strong encryption. I hope you find this useful.

Comment: I've made myself a bash script and config file that runs duplicity, and have found that http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain provides for the cron environment to use the keychain/ssh-agent-cached SSH key. `eval ``keychain --noask --eval id_rsa``` goes in the bash script. I have keychain prompt me for the key passphrase on login. From then on, duplicity, called by my script called by cron, has rsync access. I belive Keychain also does this for GnuPG keys (see bottom of project page), though my backup doesn't require that for encryption so far, which I think is because the diff info is cached on disk.

Comment: The line that goes in the bash script in my comment above is not displaying correctly. See project page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use duplicity-automate (http://duplicity-auto.sf.net/).

It supports nice XML syntax, and have some handlers for making MySQL/PostgreSQL db dumps.

Just define two files like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<duplicity-automate>
 <backups>
   <backup type="dir">
     <passphrase>abcdef</passphrase>
     <remote-name>home</remote-name>
     <local-path>/home</local-path>
     <expiry-period>1Y</expiry-period>
   </backup>

   <backup type="dir">
     <passphrase>qwerty</passphrase>
     <remote-name>config</remote-name>
     <local-path>/etc</local-path>
     <expiry-period>1Y</expiry-period>
   </backup>
 </backups>
</duplicity-automate>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<duplicity-automate>
 <servers>
   <server>
     <protocol>ftp</protocol>
     <username>john</username>
     <hostname>example.com</hostname>
     <password>1234</password>
     <path>mydirectory/backups</path>
   </server>
 </servers>
</duplicity-automate>
```

and that's it!

Comment: Could I convince you to switch to yaml or something less verbose for user config? This looks promising.

Comment: "nice XML syntax" :)

Comment: @ppetraki I no longer maintain the project and when it was created there were not that many nice tools to parse config files from the command line other than XML in the standard ubuntu repositories. Nowdays I would have chosen something else but I don't want to put any additional effort. It is what it is.