# Will Deja Dup make it's scheduled backup if user isn't logged in?

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

There are several users on one PC - user1, user2... User2 has a scheduled daily backup. Will Deja Dup make user2's daily incremental backup, while user1 is logged in and using the PC?

Answer (score 4):

[From the deja dup page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/HowItWorks):

> **Duplicity**
>
> Déjà Dup is really just a clever graphical wrapper around the command
> line backup tool [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/). You can read more about it on its
> homepage, but basically, it uses rsync to generate incremental,
> encrypted backup volumes.
>
> **Scheduling**
>
> Déjà Dup does not use cron or similar schedulers. **Rather, it starts a
> program deja-dup-monitor when you log into your session**. This keeps
> track of when you last successfully backed up and will wait until the
> next scheduled backup.
>
> It determines exactly when the next scheduled backup is largely on its
> own, based on the user's preferences about whether to backup once a
> day, once a week, etc.
>
> **Why Not Cron?**
>
> One disadvantage is that a backup can not be started while a user is not logged in. The primary use case for Déjà Dup is backing up user data, so this is not a large concern, as user data is unlikely to change while the user are not logged in.

So no.

But Deja Dup is just a graphical front end for `duplicity`. Examples on automating that: [Automating duplicity backups using cron](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309765/automating-duplicity-backups-using-cron) or the [Ubuntu wiki on duplicity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DuplicityBackupHowto).

Comment: What about if I log with user2, leave it, switch user and log with user1? I will have both sessions running, with user2 in the back, but will the backup run as it should?

Comment: It says in above you need to login. It does not state you need to stay logged in. What happens is that your session will check the backup procedure and schedule a task to execute it (and that task will remain as long as the system is up and running). So I doubt you need to keep user 2 logged in. Try it I would say ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As Rinzwind said back in 2015, there is no way to schedule backups that run with no user logged in. However, even though I know the question is specific to deja dup, I will share the solution I found to solve the problem: I installed "Back in Time" (a rsync backend). Back in Time allows scheduled backups to run even if the user is not logged in. You can find it at https://github.com/bit-team/backintime or in the "Ubuntu Software" library.