# How to move all installed programs from my computer to another computer or laptop?

Tags: installation, package-management

If I have installed a lot of programs/games on my computer(desktop) and now buy a new laptop and I have installed a Ubuntu 11.10 on it too then,how to move all installed programs on my desktop to my laptop instead of installing them again on my laptop ???

Comment: IMO reinstalling all of your games on your laptop would be easier than trying to "move" them over from your desktop. What is your reason for wanting this? Are you trying to preserve configuration and save data, avoid having to re-download, or what?

Comment: Avoid reinstall, avoid re-download, avoid power consuming, and enhance battery life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)open nautilus with sudo nautilus command , go to  var/cache/
apt/archives 
select and copy the folder with packages u have downloaded .(if it gives error , just click on skip and Dont worry )

2)paste it to a external drive . also copy and paste your home folder .
3)copy and paste both folders in your second pc.
4)install synaptic package manager in second pc , click on add downloaded packages from menu and point to the location u copied archive  folder.
it will add them and mark them automatically . if it gives error for broken packages , update cache with update manager or reload and click on 'fix broken packages' from menu .
5)click on apply . u will have to download only if there is new version available for something .
6)after installation copy the home folder to your home. restart your system.

by following this procedure u will have clean system and u will have to download least .

Comment: But i haven't found apt directory in var(do i have to install synaptic, i haven't installed synaptic on my desktop)

Comment: mmm, this directory contain a lot of .dep packages is there any way to add all installed programs and games in one executable file

Comment: here u don't need to do that, coz all the packages will be marked automatically for installation as soon as they are added.

Comment: Sorry, i need it and it is the only way to do the job (what is the meaning of `coz`)

Comment: coz is because .   and when u click on 'add downloaded packages' in synaptic menu , and when they are added after the process , you Dont need to mark them individually , they all get marked automatically and you just have to click on apply  to install everything .  if you Dont want to install everything you downloaded , then you will have to manually unmark packages you Dont want to install .

Answer (score 5):

Best way to do that is a full backup of your system and then restore it the the new disk.

You have basically 3 choices:

- Full manual system installation, all programs and configurations done
  one by one or using any automated process of installing the packages that you had. Configuration of those packages will probably be necessary after installation, with a bit of luck you will be able to "move" all your programs configuration by copying your `home` folder from the old computer to the new one;
- Full system backup done with backups tools such as `deja-dup` which
  will then be restored to the new system;
- Disk cloning from the old system to the new. An image can be made
  from your old system and then restored to the new one leaving your
  system identical as the previous one. You can use dedicated applications such as [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or a more simple approach suck as [dd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-drive-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install/78084#78084);

In the end its options 2 and 3 will make the all process faster and no (mostly no) downloads needed but option 1 will leave you with a cleaner system.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to remember that as long as you copy your home directory onto the new computer, all your apps will be automatically configured and ready to use when you install them. You don't have to reconfigure anything.

Comment: but i have re-download them and reinstall them

Answer (score 0):

As techvish81 said you just have a copy of your hard disk. If you didn't find the .deb packages just search for it in Nautilus if you don't like the command-line approach.I'm sure you will get it.

And then place all the .debs you want in a folder and run the following command

> sudo dpkg -i *.deb

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121243/how-to-install-debs-in-a-folder-using-a-single-command)

Answer (score 0):

So if you're on Ubuntu 20 DON'T try to use rsync like I did. It did not work as expected instead I recommend just copying partitions via gparted specifically both the root file system (obviously) and the efi (fat32) file system, that should work just fine.