# How to install .debs in a folder using a single command?

Tags: 12.04, deb

Hello I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2 and I've got the .debs of the softwares I had been using in Oneiric. I wanna install them all!! But the problem is I can't install them one by one [due to shortage of time and patience].

Is there any command to install all the .debs placed in a single folder once and for all!!

Comment: You can install .deds by using Gdebi package manager and its easy to use just locate it and install,remove or reinstall.@SuchithJN

Answer (score 28, accepted):

here is how 
Click the Dash -> type Terminal

open up the terminal

then type `cd` PATH_TO_THE_FOLDER_CONTAINING_THE_DEBS

then run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

basically, what this does is fills in the rest of the name in place of the * character. You may encounter an error saying dependencies not met, if you see this then you can run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This usually will cause apt to download the missing dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

This command should help.

Go into the folder using the terminal and then type:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -R` does a recursive directory install.

```
sudo dpkg -R /path/to/folder
```