# How to move ubuntu 12.04 on another drive

Tags: 12.04, dd, boot-partition

How I can move my ubuntu on another drive?

I know about clonezilla but problem is that destination drive is smaller the source one. Gparted can't copy-paste partition if destination not the end last partition.

I tried `dpkg --selected-packages` and `apt-clone`. First one just not install all my packages and removed existed that now I have no full Unity and not my all packages. Second one just fail on configuration package. But before I did that way I copy-paste my `/etc` to the new system.

My partition table:

```
destination: gpt
 1     1049kB  106MB   105MB   fat32             EFI System  загрузочный
 2     106MB   12,1GB  12,0GB  ext4
 3     12,1GB  66,3GB  54,2GB  ext4

source: msdos
 1     1049kB  12,0GB  12,0GB  primary  ext4              загрузочный
 2     12,0GB  492GB   480GB   primary  ext4
 3     492GB   500GB   8107MB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
```

GPT not working with Ubuntu that use grub 1.99. I don't know why but my laptop can't boot any device with UEFI, just black screen and Ubuntu detect it on fresh install.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install

Comment: This is not duplicate. I'm trying understand how make that kind migration correct from bigger drive with MBR to smaller SSD with GPT. Any body can tell me which difference between flags (boot, boot_grub) and Bios setup partition (in ubuntu installer). Thanks.

Comment: Partitions are described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace