# How do I move my Ubuntu (only) 12.04.1 to a new disk

Tags: hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace my disk without having to rebuild my Ubuntu install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install)

I've copied it and I believe that it is now booting from the right place - but I'm not really sure how I got there.  I'd like to:

- verify My Ubuntu install is now booting from the new disk (and maybe understand for sure how I did it).
- delete the other partitions (That's easy with fdisk - but I'm afraid to do anything now because it got so messed up before.
- Then expand my Ubuntu partition so it has more room.  (Again I know how to add blocks with fdisk but I'm afraid to do that without some advise.  From what I've read it can get messed up easily.)
- Clean the junk out of the boot menu
- Then reinstall windows 8 on the other HDD and either not let it overwrite the MBR on the drive Grub2 is booting from, or just recover Grub2 afterwards.

'Boot-repair' session number.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1453284

Answer (score 0):

Just from experience, it's always easier to install the Win OS first, and then install Ubuntu on whichever partition you want (same or different disk).
Grub is indeed more flexible with multi-boot than Win OS and there might be chances that your Win 8 will without confirmation overwrite the MBR

Comment: Thx.  :)  Win 8 was installed first but got corrupted trying to get Ubuntu to a new drive.  So I'll need to install again once I get the partitions deleted.