# error fsyncing/closing/dev/sda: input/output error - hdd not detected in BIOS after this error

Tags: boot, partitioning, gnome, 15.04

So here's what happened: I created a ubuntu gnome bootable usb using [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) and selected to replace my windows and install a fresh copy of ubuntu. But as soon as ubuntu  finished cleaning up windows and formatting i got the error `error fsyncing/closing/dev/sda: input/output error`

I had no choice so I restarted my system and now my HDD is not detected in BIOS and also not in ubuntu live boot mode.

I have a Sony vaio.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I/O errors usually (but not always) indicate failing hardware. My guess is that your disk (or some other disk-related component, like a cable or your motherboard's disk controller circuitry) was on its last legs, and the "exercise" involved in installing Ubuntu caused it to fail. You don't say what prompted you to install Ubuntu, but if you were having problems with Windows reliability, it's possible that this was an earlier symptom of the problem.

You might try unplugging your disk (from both ends of the cable if it's a desktop system) and plugging it back in again. You could also try running a [SMART test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04) from an Ubuntu live CD -- but if the disk isn't detected by your firmware, it might not even show up in Ubuntu, which would make such a test impossible.

If you've got a spare disk, you could try using it instead. If it works, then you can pretty much conclude that your old disk is dead. If the replacement disk fails, too, then chances are the problem is with your computer motherboard's circuitry.

Comment: I tried to install ubuntu as my windows installation has gone painfully slow. Even a click on my computer was taking like forever to execute. Luckily linux mint was installed after several attemps though with too may errors. What you say is absolutely right as both `badblocks` and mint's disk utility show poor disk health. The message says and I quote `failure is imminent`

Comment: In that case, *power down the computer immediately.* You can then go to a computer store and buy a new replacement disk; or if you can go without the computer for a day or two, order a replacement online. See [this question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78076/how-to-replace-my-disk-without-having-to-rebuild-my-ubuntu-install) for instructions on copying your system. (If this is a laptop, you may need a docking port or USB/SATA adapter to temporarily connect the disk, or use a desktop system to do the copying.)

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct for Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Linux.  My SSD drive is in good shape, and is connected through a USB converter.  Yet, I get this error when trying to rsync linux boot files to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace older cables and defective HDD

It worked for me. However, similar happened when I was performing Debian 10 installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter that problem you definitely have a defective HDD or a problem in the partitions
Encountered the error when trying to instal bionic beaver when Windows failed to boot on the laptop..
I had to re instal Windows to organize the dis partitions then installed Ubuntu and wiped the windows data in the process

It worked!!