# Can't install Ubuntu because of 'error fsyncing/closing/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: input/output'

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my PC. During the installation process a dialogue box appears with the following message:

```
error fsyncing/closing/dev/mmcblk0rpmb: input/output error
```

Selecting **retry** brings the same notification, while **ignore** continues to the installation. Once the installation is complete, and following with the restart prompt, I am brought back to the boot screen, where I can (once again) choose **try, install or OEM install**. However it is clear that the system is booted using the USB, but not the internal drive.

I am using an  ASUS Eeebook X205TA, with an SSD.

If I turn the computer off and remove the USB, no boot takes place.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have a feeling that it is probably a corrupt .iso file. I was having problems with the mate 64 bit Mint 17.3. I then downloaded xubuntu and using the same USB was able to have my laptop ASUS E402MA up and running without any problems. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced older cables and defective HDs, it worked my Debian 10 installation.

See the question [655659](https://askubuntu.com/questions/655659/error-fsyncing-closing-dev-sda-input-output-error-hdd-not-detected-in-bios-af/1219117)